# getting an error that my dnsl has no records

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

here is my code im so lost any help is greatly appreciated

```
$ORIGIN centos.local.
$TTL 86400
@       SOA     dnsl.centos.local.      hostmaster.centos.local. (
                2001062501 ; serial
                21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                604800     ; expire after 1 week
                86400      ; minimum TTL of 1 day
)
        In NS   dns1.centos.local.


@       In A    172.16.159.26
```

Comment: I've been bitten by this before - you know that you can't use the `.local` TLD for a machine? That's defined as a multicast address... Maybe change that to `centos.lan.`

Comment: That aside, what error are you actually getting? What's the exact text, what program or app is showing it, and what are you trying to do when you get the error?